# Writing the result of a for-loop to the webpage using innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

I am learning Javascript and I am now getting bored of the console, so I would like to "write" to the webpage itself.

I am writing the result of a for loop to the page, I want to print the result, putting a comma after every index, I have managed to accomplish this but there is a comma at the end of the last result, how do I stop the comma after the 9th index? I assume I need to use an index of some sort (i[9]) but I'm not sure how to say stop writing commas.

Here is my code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("para1");
x.innerHTML = "Result: ";
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    result= i + "," + " ";
x.innerHTML += result;
}
```

One other thing, I am printing "result" in the x variable's innerHTML, is there another way to write variable except in the actual HTML of the page? for instance in the x.innerHTML at the end?

I would greatly appriciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: For your second question, there are other ways to output variables. You can use JS frameworks (for example, **jQuery**). Most of those frameworks will do DOM manipulation using the basic JS methods and attributes (like `innerHTML`).

Comment: The native way to add html would be: `var resultElem = document.createElement("div");  resultElem.innerText = result; document.body.appendChild(resultElem);`  You can use `appendChild` for any DOM element, not just `document.body`.

Comment: this is jquery, correct?

Comment: My comment uses Native JavaScript.

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid DOM manipulation you can simply use `document.write(result);`

Comment: ah ok, thanks for all your help, I will take this on board and try different things!

Comment: I used the above code but ammended it:http://jsfiddle.net/6jy7399j/ when I run this is knocks out my CSS, I have a white main content div at 900px wide but it gets rid of it, why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an array and then after the loop has finished, join the array on `,` and then append to the innerHTML:

```
var x = document.getElementById("para1");
var result = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    result.push(i);
}
x.innerHTML = "Result: " + result.join(", ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! ah ok, so an array, is the push method populating the empty array?

Comment: @Addioioi Yes. `push()` adds an element to the end of an array.

Comment: [push and join docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: so to help me understand this, result.push is placing 1,2,3.. into the array?

Comment: when you use `result.push(i)` you are adding the value of `i` into the array. You can see this if you add a `console.log("Result Array: ", result);` after you push it into the array. This way you can see it being built. After the loop ends you have a full array of [1,2,3,4,...11]. To get a String that is delimited by a comma you need to join the elements together on comma.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the explaination! totally unrelated, I have now built an array of names, bill, ben, tom. how would I print bill, ben and tom? so using the for loop still but before the last element in the array I want to add "and".

Comment: I would use the `slice` method to return a sub array of the elements, short of the last element, which you can then join with commas. Then append the last element to the string with the `, and`. `var str = result.slice(0,result.length-1).join(", ") + " and " + result[result.length-1];`

Comment: documentation on slice is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice Note it doesn't modify the original array, just returns a new array of the indicated sub-set. Another method called splice (whomever named these two deserve a reward...) will modify the original array.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to do something different for the last one, you have to do it differently:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("para1");
 x.innerHTML = "Result: ";
 for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {   // one less here
     result= i + "," + " ";      // this could be result = i + ", ";
     x.innerHTML += result ;
    }

 result = "10";            // this could be made shorter. I wanted it to parellel 
 x.innerHTML += result;    // the code above.
```

UPDATE:
To make it more obvious....

original way:

```
 var n = 10;
 for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     DoSomething(i);
    }
```

revised way:

```
 var n = 10;
 for(var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
     DoSometing(i);
    }

 DoSomethingSpecialLastCase(n)
```

Comment: This is what I love about Javascript, theres always multiple ways of doing the same thing! thanks

Comment: the result = "10", is this just putting 10 on the end of the array? hence no comma?

Comment: @DavidSherret: No, I didn't.  The += comes on the next line.

Comment: @JamesCurran oh haha, i completely misread that code. I read it that you were appending to `result` and then would set the `innerHTML` finally at the end.